# add content to page from form input - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple "to do" app that is built via jquery. 
The idea is to have a form input that will accept a string, have that string become a variable that will then be added to a "list" as a new "item." The problem is that these new items (that should appear as new HTML p elements) are not showing up once the Submit button is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>To Do</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="jumbotron">
               <h1>To Do List</h1>
              <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="listInput" placeholder="add items here">
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </form>
              <br/>
              <p class="list">
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".button").click(function(){
        var add = $('input[name=listInput]').val();
    $('.list').append('<p class="item">' + add + '</p>');
    });


     $(document).on('click','.item', function() {
    $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

THE JSFIDDLE IS HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/EUq8P/2/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the button is a `submit button` which causes the pages to refresh on click by the default action of the button

Also there is problem with the input field selector, your selector will not work because the input field does not have the name `listInput`, it has the id `listInput`, so you need to use [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector)

One solution is to prevent the default action of the button by calling the preventDefault() method of the event

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".button").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var add = $('#listInput').val();
        $('.list').append('<p class="item">' + add + '</p>');
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.item', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v3Shv/)

Another is to change the type of the button from submit to button

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JGS6F/)

Comment: you're absolutely right about the submit button. I changed it to a simple "button" type. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/8XfQT/

culprit was: `var add = $('input[name=listInput]').val();`

- it should be `var add = $('input[id=listInput]').val();`

Hope rest help you out `:)`
**code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".button").click(function () {
        var add = $('input[id=listInput]').val();
        $('.list').append('<p class="item">' + add + '</p>');
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.item', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });

});
```